# Not able to add Add dependency in my GoogleMaps Project

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

i am making an application to show Google MAps , i am refrencing [this link](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

After i download the google-play-service project into SDK

path  `\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib`

When i try to import this `google-play-services_lib` project into my project explorer it shows no project was found to import

Project content contains[image]

once i import this project eclipse says `No Project Found` please check snap shot

[image]

What i am missing so that i can google-play-service_lib to show my map, Please help!!

Thanks in advance !! :)

Comment: follow the steps here http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: Create Android Project from Existing code.New->Android->Android Project from Existing code

Comment: Thou i have imported my project in project how can i add dependency in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to import as below by following steps:

```
1) Copy the path of your library.
2) In you Eclipse select File menu>New>Project...
3) From dialog select Android>Android Project from Existing Code and paste your path of the library and add it in your eclipse.
```

[image]

[image]

**EDITED:**

[image]
That's it.

Comment: @GrlsHu i was successfull to do so how can i add dependemcy to my project

Comment: Are you trying to ask that you want to add this library in your project ?

Comment: @GrlsHu yes i am asking this

Comment: You add the dependency in your project by right click > Properties>Android> library>Add and select your library project and add it. Check out screen shot in edited answer.

Comment: @GrlsHu When i pasted the google-play-services_lib project in same worksppce and then i follow the same steps it does not show

Comment: Where is does not show ? If you want to add the project as library then you must have to add it in your workspace.

Comment: @GrlsHu It gives me Error , When i do so Description Resource
Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\NewWorkSpace\myproject\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist

Comment: @raghav chopra try to clean your project.

Answer (score 1):

try Like this,

**RightClick>new>Project>Android>Android Project from Existing Code**

Select your Library project from location.

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks Amit for Support But not able to add dependency to my project

Comment: @raghavchopra Right Click your project>properties>Android>Add Your Library Project>Apply>Ok

Comment: Guota  i am doing it like this way but when i click on add nothing shows up everything freexed

Comment: @raghavchopra both the project should be in the same workspace? Just check once.

Comment: When i pasted the google-play-services_lib project in same worksppce and then i follow the same steps it does not show

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is some problem with the Google-play-services library you downloaded.
Because as you see by the guide and from the answers given here the behavior you experience
not how it suppose to be.

I would try to uninstall it using the `SDK Manager`. And re-download it again.
Then try to reference it all over again.